# End of the simple puzzle game needed AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, procedure, puzzle

I am new here, and new in the AS3 and Flash world. First, sorry 'bout my bad English. :/

I'm trying to make the end of the game, namely, when a player sort all the pieces of the puzzle in the matrix, I want to display text "Game Over".

There are several options how to solve the puzzle, so I need to make some kind of function (I think) , but I do not know how.

[Here is the printscreen of puzzle game.](http://s18.postimg.org/lhbs2bpe1/Game.jpg)

plavo, ljubicasto, zuto, crveno, narandzasto and zeleno are names of the objects (puzzle pieces)

```
Here is code:

stop();


var zutoStartX:Number = 210;
var zutoStartY:Number = 630;
var crvenoStartX:Number = 640;
var crvenoStartY:Number = 210;
var plavoStartX:Number = 430;
var plavoStartY:Number = 675;
var narandzastoStartX:Number = 890;
var narandzastoStartY:Number = 170;
var zelenoStartX:Number = 860;
var zelenoStartY:Number = 400;
var ljubicastoStartX:Number = 640;
var ljubicastoStartY:Number = 502;


var bojeArr:Array = new Array (plavo, zuto, crveno,
 zeleno, ljubicasto, narandzasto);
for (var i:uint =0; i < bojeArr.length; i++)
{
    bojeArr[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
    bojeArr[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
}
function drag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.startDrag();
}
function drop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stopDrag();

     //testiranje i vracanje na mesto ukoliko dodje do preklapanja
    if (crveno.hitCrv.hitTestObject(plavo.hitPl))
    {


        plavo.x = plavo.x;
        plavo.y = plavo.y;
        crveno.x = crvenoStartX;
        crveno.y = crvenoStartY;
    }
    else if (crveno.hitCrv.hitTestObject(zuto.hitZt))
    {


        zuto.x = zuto.x;
        zuto.y = zuto.y;
        crveno.x = crvenoStartX;
        crveno.y = crvenoStartY;
    }
    else if (crveno.hitCrv.hitTestObject(zeleno.hitZl))
    {


        zeleno.x = zeleno.x;
        zeleno.y = zeleno.y;
        crveno.x = crvenoStartX;
        crveno.y = crvenoStartY;
    }
    else if (crveno.hitCrv.hitTestObject(ljubicasto.hitLjub))
    {


        ljubicasto.x = ljubicasto.x;
        ljubicasto.y = ljubicasto.y;
        crveno.x = crvenoStartX;
        crveno.y = crvenoStartY;
    }
    else if (crveno.hitCrv.hitTestObject(narandzasto.hitNar))
    {


        crveno.x = crvenoStartX;
        crveno.y = crvenoStartY;
        narandzasto.x = narandzasto.x;
        narandzasto.y = narandzasto.y;


    }
    else if (plavo.hitPl.hitTestObject(crveno.hitCrv))
    {


        crveno.x = crveno.x;
        crveno.y = crveno.y;
        plavo.x = plavoStartX;
        plavo.y = plavoStartY;


    }
    else if (plavo.hitPl.hitTestObject(zuto.hitZt))
    {


        zuto.x = zuto.x;
        zuto.y = zuto.y;
        plavo.x = plavoStartX;
        plavo.y = plavoStartY;


    }
    else if (plavo.hitPl.hitTestObject(zeleno.hitZl))
    {


        zeleno.x = zeleno.x;
        zeleno.y = zeleno.y;
        plavo.x = plavoStartX;
        plavo.y = plavoStartY;


    }
    else if (plavo.hitPl.hitTestObject(ljubicasto.hitLjub))
    {


        ljubicasto.x = ljubicasto.x;
        ljubicasto.y = ljubicasto.y;
        plavo.x = plavoStartX;
        plavo.y = plavoStartY;


    }
    else if (plavo.hitPl.hitTestObject(narandzasto.hitNar))
    {


        narandzasto.x = narandzasto.x;
        narandzasto.y = narandzasto.y;
        plavo.x = plavoStartX;
        plavo.y = plavoStartY;


    }
    else if (zuto.hitZt.hitTestObject(crveno.hitCrv))
    {


        crveno.x = crveno.x;
        crveno.y = crveno.y;
        zuto.x = zutoStartX;
        zuto.y = zutoStartY;


    }
    else if (zuto.hitZt.hitTestObject(plavo.hitPl))
    {


        plavo.x = plavo.x;
        plavo.y = plavo.y;
        zuto.x = zutoStartX;
        zuto.y = zutoStartY;


    }
    else if (zuto.hitZt.hitTestObject(zeleno.hitZl))
    {


        zeleno.x = zeleno.x;
        zeleno.y = zeleno.y;
        zuto.x = zutoStartX;
        zuto.y = zutoStartY;


    }
    else if (zuto.hitZt.hitTestObject(ljubicasto.hitLjub))
    {


        ljubicasto.x = ljubicasto.x;
        ljubicasto.y = ljubicasto.y;
        zuto.x = zutoStartX;
        zuto.y = zutoStartY;


    }
    else if (zuto.hitZt.hitTestObject(narandzasto.hitNar))
    {


        narandzasto.x = narandzasto.x;
        narandzasto.y = narandzasto.y;
        zuto.x = zutoStartX;
        zuto.y = zutoStartY;


    }
    else if (zeleno.hitZl.hitTestObject(crveno.hitCrv))
    {


        crveno.x = crveno.x;
        crveno.y = crveno.y;
        zeleno.x = zelenoStartX;
        zeleno.y = zelenoStartY;


    }
    else if (zeleno.hitZl.hitTestObject(plavo.hitPl))
    {


        plavo.x = plavo.x;
        plavo.y = plavo.y;
        zeleno.x = zelenoStartX;
        zeleno.y = zelenoStartY;


    }
    else if (zeleno.hitZl.hitTestObject(zuto.hitZt))
    {


        zuto.x = zuto.x;
        zuto.y = zuto.y;
        zeleno.x = zelenoStartX;
        zeleno.y = zelenoStartY;


    }
    else if (zeleno.hitZl.hitTestObject(ljubicasto.hitLjub))
    {


        ljubicasto.x = ljubicasto.x;
        ljubicasto.y = ljubicasto.y;
        zeleno.x = zelenoStartX;
        zeleno.y = zelenoStartY;


    }
    else if (zeleno.hitZl.hitTestObject(narandzasto.hitNar))
    {


        narandzasto.x = narandzasto.x;
        narandzasto.y = narandzasto.y;
        zeleno.x = zelenoStartX;
        zeleno.y = zelenoStartY;


    }






      //smestanje zutog dela


    if (zuto.zt1_bt.hitTestObject(tar1))
    {
        zuto.x = 150;
        zuto.y = 200;
    }
    else if (zuto.zt1_bt.hitTestObject(tar2))
    {
        zuto.x = 250;
        zuto.y = 200;
    }
    else if (zuto.zt1_bt.hitTestObject(tar3))
    {
        zuto.x = 350;
        zuto.y = 200;
    }
    else if (zuto.zt1_bt.hitTestObject(tar4))
    {
        zuto.x = 450;
        zuto.y = 200;
    }
    else if (zuto.zt1_bt.hitTestObject(tar5))
    {
        zuto.x = 150;
        zuto.y = 300;
    }
    else if (zuto.zt1_bt.hitTestObject(tar6))
    {
        zuto.x = 250;
        zuto.y = 300;
    }
    else if (zuto.zt1_bt.hitTestObject(tar7))
    {
        zuto.x = 350;
        zuto.y = 300;
    }
    else if (zuto.zt1_bt.hitTestObject(tar8))
    {
        zuto.x = 450;
        zuto.y = 300;
    }
    else if (zuto.zt1_bt.hitTestObject(tar9))
    {
        zuto.x = 150;
        zuto.y = 400;
    }
    else if (zuto.zt1_bt.hitTestObject(tar10))
    {
        zuto.x = 250;
        zuto.y = 400;
    }
    else if (zuto.zt1_bt.hitTestObject(tar11))
    {
        zuto.x = 350;
        zuto.y = 400;
    }
    else if (zuto.zt1_bt.hitTestObject(tar12))
    {
        zuto.x = 450;
        zuto.y = 400;
    }
    else
    {
        zuto.x = zutoStartX;
        zuto.y = zutoStartY;
    }

//smestanje narandzastog dela


    if (narandzasto.nar1_bt.hitTestObject(tar1))
    {
        zuto.x = 150;
        zuto.y = 200;
    }
    else if (narandzasto.nar1_bt.hitTestObject(tar2))
    {
        narandzasto.x = 250;
        narandzasto.y = 200;
    }
    else if (narandzasto.nar1_bt.hitTestObject(tar3))
    {
        narandzasto.x = 350;
        narandzasto.y = 200;
    }
    else if (narandzasto.nar1_bt.hitTestObject(tar4))
    {
        narandzasto.x = 450;
        narandzasto.y = 200;
    }
    else if (narandzasto.nar1_bt.hitTestObject(tar5))
    {
        narandzasto.x = 150;
        narandzasto.y = 300;
    }
    else if (narandzasto.nar1_bt.hitTestObject(tar6))
    {
        narandzasto.x = 250;
        narandzasto.y = 300;
    }
    else if (narandzasto.nar1_bt.hitTestObject(tar7))
    {
        narandzasto.x = 350;
        narandzasto.y = 300;
    }
    else if (narandzasto.nar1_bt.hitTestObject(tar8))
    {
        narandzasto.x = 450;
        narandzasto.y = 300;
    }
    else if (narandzasto.nar1_bt.hitTestObject(tar9))
    {
        narandzasto.x = 150;
        narandzasto.y = 400;
    }
    else if (narandzasto.nar1_bt.hitTestObject(tar10))
    {
        narandzasto.x = 250;
        narandzasto.y = 400;
    }
    else if (narandzasto.nar1_bt.hitTestObject(tar11))
    {
        narandzasto.x = 350;
        narandzasto.y = 400;
    }
    else if (narandzasto.nar1_bt.hitTestObject(tar12))
    {
        narandzasto.x = 450;
        narandzasto.y = 400;
    }
    else
    {
        narandzasto.x = narandzastoStartX;
        narandzasto.y = narandzastoStartY;
    }

//smestanje crvenog dela


    if (crveno.crv1_bt.hitTestObject(tar1))
    {
        crveno.x = 200;
        crveno.y = 200;
    }
    else if (crveno.crv1_bt.hitTestObject(tar2))
    {
        crveno.x = 300;
        crveno.y = 200;
    }
    else if (crveno.crv1_bt.hitTestObject(tar3))
    {
        crveno.x = 400;
        crveno.y = 200;
    }
    else if (crveno.crv1_bt.hitTestObject(tar5))
    {
        crveno.x = 200;
        crveno.y = 300;
    }
    else if (crveno.crv1_bt.hitTestObject(tar6))
    {
        crveno.x = 300;
        crveno.y = 300;
    }
    else if (crveno.crv1_bt.hitTestObject(tar7))
    {
        crveno.x = 400;
        crveno.y = 300;
    }
    else if (crveno.crv1_bt.hitTestObject(tar9))
    {
        crveno.x = 200;
        crveno.y = 400;
    }
    else if (crveno.crv1_bt.hitTestObject(tar10))
    {
        crveno.x = 300;
        crveno.y = 400;
    }
    else if (crveno.crv1_bt.hitTestObject(tar11))
    {
        crveno.x = 400;
        crveno.y = 400;
    }
    else
    {
        crveno.x = crvenoStartX;
        crveno.y = crvenoStartY;
    }

//smestanje plavog dela


    if (plavo.pl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar1))
    {
        plavo.x = 200;
        plavo.y = 200;
    }
    else if (plavo.pl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar2))
    {
        plavo.x = 300;
        plavo.y = 200;
    }
    else if (plavo.pl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar3))
    {
        plavo.x = 400;
        plavo.y = 200;
    }
    else if (plavo.pl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar5))
    {
        plavo.x = 200;
        plavo.y = 300;
    }
    else if (plavo.pl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar6))
    {
        plavo.x = 300;
        plavo.y = 300;
    }
    else if (plavo.pl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar7))
    {
        plavo.x = 400;
        plavo.y = 300;
    }
    else if (plavo.pl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar9))
    {
        plavo.x = 200;
        plavo.y = 400;
    }
    else if (plavo.pl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar10))
    {
        plavo.x = 300;
        plavo.y = 400;
    }
    else if (plavo.pl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar11))
    {
        plavo.x = 400;
        plavo.y = 400;
    }
    else
    {
        plavo.x = plavoStartX;
        plavo.y = plavoStartY;
    }

      //smestanje zelenog dela


    if (zeleno.zl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar1))
    {
        zeleno.x = 200;
        zeleno.y = 150;
    }
    else if (zeleno.zl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar2))
    {
        zeleno.x = 300;
        zeleno.y = 150;
    }
    else if (zeleno.zl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar3))
    {
        zeleno.x = 400;
        zeleno.y = 150;
    }
    else if (zeleno.zl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar5))
    {
        zeleno.x = 200;
        zeleno.y = 250;
    }
    else if (zeleno.zl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar6))
    {
        zeleno.x = 300;
        zeleno.y = 250;
    }
    else if (zeleno.zl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar7))
    {
        zeleno.x = 400;
        zeleno.y = 250;
    }
    else if (zeleno.zl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar9))
    {
        zeleno.x = 200;
        zeleno.y = 350;
    }
    else if (zeleno.zl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar10))
    {
        zeleno.x = 300;
        zeleno.y = 350;
    }
    else if (zeleno.zl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar11))
    {
        zeleno.x = 400;
        zeleno.y = 350;
    }
    else if (zeleno.zl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar13))
    {
        zeleno.x = 200;
        zeleno.y = 450;
    }
    else if (zeleno.zl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar14))
    {
        zeleno.x = 300;
        zeleno.y = 450;
    }
    else if (zeleno.zl1_bt.hitTestObject(tar15))
    {
        zeleno.x = 400;
        zeleno.y = 450;
    }
    else
    {
        zeleno.x = zelenoStartX;
        zeleno.y = zelenoStartY;
    }

//smestanje ljubicastog dela


    if (ljubicasto.ljub1_bt.hitTestObject(tar1))
    {
        ljubicasto.x = 200;
        ljubicasto.y = 150;
    }
    else if (ljubicasto.ljub1_bt.hitTestObject(tar2))
    {
        ljubicasto.x = 300;
        ljubicasto.y = 150;
    }
    else if (ljubicasto.ljub1_bt.hitTestObject(tar3))
    {
        ljubicasto.x = 400;
        ljubicasto.y = 150;
    }
    else if (ljubicasto.ljub1_bt.hitTestObject(tar5))
    {
        ljubicasto.x = 200;
        ljubicasto.y = 250;
    }
    else if (ljubicasto.ljub1_bt.hitTestObject(tar6))
    {
        ljubicasto.x = 300;
        ljubicasto.y = 250;
    }
    else if (ljubicasto.ljub1_bt.hitTestObject(tar7))
    {
        ljubicasto.x = 400;
        ljubicasto.y = 250;
    }
    else if (ljubicasto.ljub1_bt.hitTestObject(tar9))
    {
        ljubicasto.x = 200;
        ljubicasto.y = 350;
    }
    else if (ljubicasto.ljub1_bt.hitTestObject(tar10))
    {
        ljubicasto.x = 300;
        ljubicasto.y = 350;
    }
    else if (ljubicasto.ljub1_bt.hitTestObject(tar11))
    {
        ljubicasto.x = 400;
        ljubicasto.y = 350;
    }
    else if (ljubicasto.ljub1_bt.hitTestObject(tar13))
    {
        ljubicasto.x = 200;
        ljubicasto.y = 450;
    }
    else if (ljubicasto.ljub1_bt.hitTestObject(tar14))
    {
        ljubicasto.x = 300;
        ljubicasto.y = 450;
    }
    else if (ljubicasto.ljub1_bt.hitTestObject(tar15))
    {
        ljubicasto.x = 400;
        ljubicasto.y = 450;
    }
    else
    {
        ljubicasto.x = ljubicastoStartX;
        ljubicasto.y = ljubicastoStartY;
    }
}//restart dugme
resButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);
function reset(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    zuto.x = zutoStartX;
    zuto.y = zutoStartY;
    plavo.x = plavoStartX;
    plavo.y = plavoStartY;
    crveno.x = crvenoStartX;
    crveno.y = crvenoStartY;
    narandzasto.x = narandzastoStartX;
    narandzasto.y = narandzastoStartY;
    zeleno.x = zelenoStartX;
    zeleno.y = zelenoStartY;
    ljubicasto.x = ljubicastoStartX;
    ljubicasto.y = ljubicastoStartY;



}
```

Comment: There is no direct answer, as it depends on you, how you've built your code and how you can implement the solution. It's too broad and unclear, so try few things, narrow it down to one or two solutions and then ask again :)

Comment: Let's say I have 8 objects, of which I can make the square puzzle, in several ways. When I make a square, I want to display "Game over". I do not know how to do that. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of code duplication here that can be turned into functions (if you are doing something twice, you might as well make it possible to do it any number of times).

Also you have a lot of unnecesary code like:

```
narandzasto.x = narandzasto.x;  
narandzasto.y = narandzasto.y;
```

where you are setting a variable to it's current value.

Now, as for the solution, I think the easiest answer would be to track the collision tests for the puzzle pieces vs the grid and additionally I think you'd have to track puzzle piece vs puzzle piece collisions to detect any overlaps, and when all the pieces have been fitted to the grid and there are no overlaps you should have a completed solution.

Comment: It will not work without codes like

narandzasto.x = narandzasto.x;  
narandzasto.y = narandzasto.y;

I tried without these parts of code, but, no luck.

As for overlaps, there aren't any, 'couse of "snap to grid" effect.